# Twincat 2 - Split array of characters into array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, split, twincat

I am using Twincat2 for an old project, and get a array of chars from a TCP connection.

a sample sting is this: `CMD,011,132654,38201,ABC,23`

I would need to split this into single strings. So basically an array of strings, where myarray[0] is CMD, [1] is 011 etc..

I cannot figure out how to do this. TC3 has a split function, but how can this be done in TC2 in structured text?

Thank you

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756490/syntax-for-returning-one-character-of-string-by-index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used TC2, but here is how I would approach the problem:

1. Find position of the first `,` using [FIND](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclibstandard/11931095307.html?id=8186313126412399202)

`position := FIND(sampleString, ',');`

2. Assign characters up to this position to first string in the array using [LEFT](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclibstandard/11931098379.html?id=4272229220897820488)

`myArray[0] := LEFT(sampleString, position-1);`

3. Delete first partial string and `,` from the initial string using [DELETE](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclibstandard/11931093771.html?id=665016884003240733)

`sampleString := DELETE(sampleString, position, 1);`

4. Repeat until no `,` is found in the initial string, then assign what remains to the last element of the array

Comment: Thank you very much! trying it right away and will get back tomorrow.